# Redefine `\S` in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I want to define via `\DeclareMathOperator{\S}{\mathsf{S}}` a new operator, but it says that `\S` is already defined. How can I redefine it?

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the 'normal text definition' of `\S` as "§" in the text? If not, you could do `\let\S\relax` before `\DeclareMathOperator{\S}{\mathsf{S}}`. If you want to be able to continue using `\S` as "§" in text mode, something more complex will be needed I guess. Let me just add a warning that is in general not a great idea to define one-letter macros oneself, many names are already taken, some of which should not be overwritten. You could choose a slightly longer name such as `\opS`, many editors have features to help you write longer names more quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(updated answer to incorporate egreg's observations and suggestions)

Assuming you wish to preserve the text-mode meaning of `\S`, I suggest you proceed as shown in code below.

[image]

Preserving the text-mode meaning of `\S` is especially useful (essential, actually) if you happen to load any packages that make use of `\S`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro} % for '\LetLtxMacro' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}     % for '\operatorname' macro
\LetLtxMacro\origS\S % preserve original def. of "\S"
\renewcommand{\S}{\ifmmode\operatorname{\mathsf{S}}\else\origS\fi}

\begin{document}
\S1, $\mathsf{a}\S \mathsf{a}$, $\mathsf{a}\S(\mathsf{a})$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user372565 - You're most welcome! Incidentally, if you need the sans-serif "S" letter to be on the baseline, use `\textsf{S}` instead of `\mathsf{S}` in the redefinition of `\S`.

Comment: Beware of `\protect`; you should use `\LetLtxMacro`; and shouldn't it be `\operatorname{\mathsf{S}}`? Or the S will be lowered below the baseline as it's quite evident from the picture. And no, `\textsf{S}` would by *very* wrong. Try it in an italic context.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I'll apply the required fixes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not convinced overloading this way a command is good practice. I'm quite convinced of the contrary, actually.

Define `\opS` and you'll be on your way.

Anyhow, if you really want it, look at the definition of `\S` in `latex.ltx`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 2119:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\S}{\ifmmode\mathsection\else\textsection\fi}
```

So you see that `\S` in math mode already does something different (it prints § as a math symbol). You can just redefine `\mathsection`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand\mathsection{\operatorname{\mathsf{S}}}

\begin{document}

Text: \S

Math: $\S(a)$

\end{document}
```

[image]